# Edit selected text in a textarea and print it back to the textarea

Tags: javascript, select, replace, nicedit

I have been working on a problem for the past few days in a javascript and I now realise that I should probably rethink it from the start as I dont get it to work.

PS. It needs to work in IE8+, Chrome, FF :s
PSS. Using nicEdit, and my js is a plugin for that

Basically what I want to do is to:

- Select a text from a text area
- Click a button which start my javascript (got this sorted)
- Take the selected text and place < pre> < /pre> tags, or whatever, around it
- Paste it back into the textarea.

The things I have not been able to solve are these:

- Select and replace several rows of text
- Have the tags become actual tags and not just printed text
- Be sure that the actual text I am selecting is what gets replace, not the first occurance of the text.
- Have the text keep things such as new rows, indentions, odd signs etc.

*An example:*

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
>   sed do eiusmod tempor
>
> **(** incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
>
> aliqua.**)<-- I mark this text** Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

*And turn it into:*

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,  sed do
>   eiusmod tempor
>
> **( incididunt ut labore et dolore magna**
>
> **aliqua.) <-- All bold using my tags** Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
>   nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
>   consequat.

I could link my JS function as well if that is of any help, perheps it is possible to build off it, but I am stuck atm.

```
function() {        
    var textComponent = document.getElementById('area1');
    var selectedText;

    if (document.selection != undefined){
      selectedText = (!!document.getSelection) ? document.getSelection() :
         (!!window.getSelection)   ? window.getSelection() :
         document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    //Mozilla/Chrome version same as prev atm
    else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined){
      selectedText = (!!document.getSelection) ? document.getSelection() :
         (!!window.getSelection)   ? window.getSelection() :
         document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    var nicE = nicEditors.findEditor('area1');
    var cont = nicE.getContent();
    var str = nicE.getContent();
    var res = str.replace(selectedText,'<pre class="codePrint"><code>' + selectedText + '</code></pre>');

    nicE.setContent(res);
}
```

I don't know if this code will be to any use, but who knows. What it does atm is, find the text I have marked and replaces it (but only 1 row and the first occurrence of it, if I mark `bb` in `aa bbbb bb cc` then instead of getting `aa bbbb`**`bb`**`cc`, i get `aa`**`bb`**`bb bb cc`, which isn't what I want. I supposed I need to replace specific content given end and start positions of the selected area, but I don't know how to append these.

Comment: Do you really mean a textarea? Pretty sure you can't put HTML tags in a textarea and expect them to render.

Comment: Yes I mean a text area, and yes you can as that is what my code does atm.. just not the way I want :)

Comment: You may need to use a wysiwyg editor to get this to work properly so that it renders the tags you want to add. Something like TinyMCE or YUI rich text editor.

Comment: I am using nicEdit.. should add that into my question

Comment: @Ambrose how about `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`?

Comment: @bartek What difference would that make? I can edit it, just not the way I want. This question is a little more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by making the div `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` and then used the following code:

```
myEditor.prototype.surroundElement = function(tag,cssClass){

if(window.getSelection(document.getSelection().anchorNode) < 1){        
    if(document.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.nodeName == tag.toUpperCase()){

        var anchor = $(document.getSelection().anchorNode);

        anchor.unwrap();            
    }
}

else{

    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var newParent = document.createElement(tag);

    newParent.className = cssClass;

    try{

        range.surroundContents(newParent);
    } catch(err){

        alert("You may only style code within the same tag");
    }
}
};
```

By using `range.surroundContents(newParent);` I had an already defined function handling the tags for me. What I needed to do in return was to make sure that the selection was not covering several different tags. It is only applicable within one tag. I handled it by cleaning out div tags that where created through linebreaks etc. and error checking it with a try. I put some responsibility on the user which is not ideal, but as we are 3 people who are going to use what I have created it is acceptable.

PS. the first if statement allows me to use the same button for adding tags (a full selection) and removing them (the tags surrounding the current caret position)